# Closing a null sql connection

Tags: c#, database-connection, sqlconnection, try-catch-finally, connection-close

I have a question about closing an opened connection to a database in C#. Let's say we abandon the "using" method and use a try/catch/finally block to open and close the connection.

```
try 
{
    connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Do whatever you need with exception
}
finally
{
  1.connection.Dispose();
  2.if (connection != null)
    {
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My question here is what exactly happens if only 1) in this code segment occurs. The connection should always be checked for null before disposed(closed), but what if it isn't, and we try to close a connection object that's null? (I'm interested in what happens to the opened connection, can this lead to a leak)

Comment: If `connection` was null at 1 - impossible with your exact example as it is - then you'll get a `NullReferenceException` in the finally block on the `Dispose` which will propagate up.

Comment: `connection?.Dispose()` that doesn't work?

Comment: The same thing that happens when you try to call any method on null ^^

Comment: It throws `NullReferenceException`

Comment: But what happens to the connection previously opened? Is there a possibility it stays open and leads to a connection leak?

Comment: Unless you manually assign it to null you won't have a connection opened. If you don't close your opened connections you might run out of application pool.

Comment: What opened connection? Are you asking what happens if you open `connection` then set `connection = null` then try to do `connection.Close()`? You'll get a `NullReferenceException` and I reckon the `SqlConnection` object that `connection` used to reference before being set to `null` will sit in memory, opened, until the garbage collector picks it up.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson Yes, let's say i open a ```connection```, but DO NOT set ```connection=null``` and then try to do ```connection.close()```(without checking it for null). Why would i check the connection for null if i don't manually assign it to null is what i'm trying to find out

Comment: @Filip5991 You need to check it for `null` because you're in a `finally` block and you don't know how you got there. If you try to call `Dispose` (or any method) on a `null` object, you'll get a `NullReferenceException`. Surely it would take less time to try this out than to ask the question...unless I'm missing the question here.

Comment: Or in other words an application i'm using has a problem with the app pool as there are obviously leaks. So i was wondering if opening a ```connection``` and then closing it in the finally block without previously checking it for ```null``` could lead to those leaks

Comment: We check for null because it's a good practice.

Comment: No. It would lead to exceptions. But really, *that* should be your question, then. The question above is a little confusing, and leading to lots of "incorrect" answers because it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Connection objects should be created, used, closed, and disposed as soon as possible (in other words, they should always be created in the context of a `using` block).

Comment: @RufusL If you already need `try`/`catch` blocks (which is debatable... ime, it's usually better to let those exceptions bubble up a level), `finally` offers similar safety and conciseness. I prefer `using`, but it's too strong to say the `finally` is _wrong_.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn True. I didn't mean to imply that finally is wrong (after all that's what a using block generates behind the scenes anyway). What I meant to say (by implication, I guess), is that the problem is most likely that connections are probably not being disposed, which happens sometimes when they are shared across a class, but not something that would happen in the code presented in the question. Something for OP to check out: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query

Answer (score 0):

In the question, if `connection.Dispose()` is called on a `null` connection without the check, you cause a new exception that has not been handled, and everything that goes with that. Additionally, if this was done because the `connection` variable was set to `null` before the `finally` block without ensuring the connection was closed, *it is possible to leak that open connection* ... though as a practical matter it's rare to see code in the wild that knows to use a `finally` but also wants to set the connection to `null`.

Granting the lack of `using` (which is suspect, but whatever), I prefer this pattern:

```
finally
{
    if (connection is IDisposable) connection.Dispose();
}
```

This [still protects against `null` values](https://twitter.com/jaredpar/status/1115019017297596416?lang=en)* in the `connection` object, and is a closer mimic for what the `using` pattern was already doing behind the scenes.

Note, however, you're still missing one important feature of a `using` block, which is protection against something assigning `null` to your variable before the block closes. `using` blocks also protect your connection in a separate (hidden) variable, so you're sure you still have a valid reference at the end of the block (this is new in  C# 8).

**(For completeness, the author of that linked tweet is the lead on the C# compiler team, so he should know, and he's not being ironic).*

Comment: I'm using ```using```, i'm just hypothetically interested in what's happening if a null connection is closed

Comment: *"what's happening if a null connection is closed"* is impossible. A null connection cannot be closed.

Comment: `Dispose()` should never be called directly but by letting the compiler doing that using the `using` keyword.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I mostly agree (hence the "which is suspect" part of the answer), but **never** is a strong word.